# Javascript regular expression to check if the file ends with (.csv)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to select the last .csv in text.csv.csv 
I tried `(\.csv)$` but it didn't work.

I am using this site to test my regax 
https://regex101.com/#javascript

Comment: `/\.csv$/.test(str)`

Comment: Excuse me, that *must* ["work"](https://regex101.com/r/fK4dM3/1). Although the `.` must be escaped. Could you specify the problem?

Comment: @Tushar Doesn't that return an array? `/\.csv$/.test(str)[1]` will get ".csv" - I stand to be corrected

Comment: @NicholasRobinson  The question is _to check if the file ends with (.csv)_ and [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) returns Boolean value, not array.

Comment: @Tushar True! I retract my comment :)

Comment: I am using this site to test my regax https://regex101.com/#javascript
yes you are right, I was trying \.(csv)$ and (\.csv)$ but none of them worked

Comment: @SMH Add the code you in the question. See **[mcve]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
/\.csv$/
```

Added '\' to escape the dot.

You need to use a backslash to escape the dot character, to check if the dot is present.

If you don't escape it, the dot represents a single character, so, for example, 'test.csv.xxxcsv' would match too.

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/1yphfsvv/)

Comment: And why keep `(` and `)`?

Comment: Now, it is equal to Tushar's comment. Could you add some value to your post by adding more description, example? See, [OP does not know how to use the regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246811/javascript-regular-expression-to-check-if-the-file-ends-with-csv#comment65829688_39246811).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice Tushar's comment. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need regex for this? 
Simple JavaScript functions should suffice

```
var str = "myFileName.csv";
var index = str.lastIndexOf(".csv");

var len = str.length;
var res = "";
if(len - index  == 4) 
{
res = "CSV Found"
} 
else {
res = "CSV Not Found"
};
```

Comment: You are correct. Edited the answer to use **lastIndexOf** instead of **indexOf**

Comment: Ahhhh, I checked the edited answer and deleted my comment, because I thought that I missed 'last' in 'lastIndexOf'. But yeah, now that should work. But it's longer that a regular expression though.